# Simple jQuery function to check the div ClassName

Tags: jquery, classname

I have written a very simple function for checking the tag class name.
I attached it to the div(s) by using `.attr()` and it seems no problem to alert.

However, `$(this).attr('class')` cannot show the correct class name and just display

> "undefined"

. 
Actually, I have more things want to do with `$(this)`, so it is really bad that i stop at the very beginning.

Would anyone tell me why this happened and how to fix it?

```
<div class="testing class1" >Something here</div>
<div class="testing class2" >Something here</div>    
<script>

$("div.testing").attr('onclick', 'checkClass()');

function checkClass(){
  alert( $(this).attr('class'));
  // what do something more with "$(this)"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass this to the function because `$(this) = window;`

please try this :

```
$("div.testing").attr('onclick', 'checkClass(this)');
function checkClass(e){
  alert( e.className);
  // what do something more with e, this is you clicked element
}
```

Comment: For using JQuery, it's handy for just changing  $(this) into $(e). Very simple way to solve this problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing it the following way, your code will output `undefined` inside alert because `this` references `checkClass()` function and not the element you are trying to target,
see the demo below, you should learn how to make a simple [plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

```js
$.fn.checkClass = function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
  });
}
$("div.testing").checkClass();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testing class1">Something here</div>
<div class="testing class2">Something here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although jQuery have own methods for adding / removing classes from / to elements, for enumeration have nothing. So you should use native js method.

```js
var checkClass = e => {
  alert(e.target.classList)
}

$("div.testing").click(checkClass)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testing class1" >Something here</div>
<div class="testing class2" >Something here</div>
```